# Speeding up naming vector in Rcpp

Tags: r, vector, attributes, rcpp, names

I started to use Rcpp and be able to speed up R-code incredibly. However changing names of vector elements (like 'v.attr("names")=X' or 'v.names()=X') is very slow in my hand. Is there any solutions to improve? Plese see attached example.

sample of rcpp; test_names.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test_names(int N, bool name){

  RNGScope scope;
  NumericVector data = runif(N, 1, 100);

  if(name)data.attr("names")=seq(1,N);

  return data;
}
```

The result I got in R

```
> sourceCpp("./test_names.cpp")
> system.time(test_names(10000000, F))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.139   0.025   0.164 
> system.time(test_names(10000000, T))
   user  system elapsed 
 5.181   0.117   5.296
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think creating that many strings is taking too much times and you can't do anything about it. See these comparisons:

```
> N <- 1e6

> system.time(test_names(N, FALSE))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.001   0.009 

> system.time(test_names(N, TRUE))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.244   0.001   0.246 

> system.time(setNames(test_names(N, FALSE), seq_len(N)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.236   0.001   0.238 

> system.time(seq_len(N))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.001 

> system.time(as.character(seq_len(N)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.228   0.000   0.229
```

It is really the conversion to strings which is slow.

I don't usually use names; why do you need them?

Answer (score 0):

Naming an object from start to finish is going to take time as @F.Prive points out, converting a vector to characters is quite expensive. Generally speaking, naming an object is regarded more of as a convenience than 
a necessity and when a "need for speed" user is faced with the option, they will gladly give up this convenience. This is why some developers give the option to return a named object.

Nevertheless, there are other options out there for naming objects, so let's see if any of them speed up the process.

**Option `Base R` :** 
Sometimes, very basic functions in `base R`, such as `names`, can be very efficient.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector test_namesBaseNameCpp(int N){
    Rcpp::RNGScope scope;
    return Rcpp::runif(N, 1, 100);
}

## in base R define the following:
test_namesBaseNameR <- function(n, named) {
    v <- test_namesBaseNameCpp(N = n)
    if (named)
        names(v) <- 1:n
    v
}
```

Here are the results:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP = test_names(10^5, T),
               baseR = test_namesBaseNameR(10^5, T),
               unit = "relative")
               Unit: relative
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
    OP 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
 baseR 1.008021 1.001896 1.015566 1.001912 1.016359 1.101542   100
```

Virtually the same.

**Option Passing names as argument :**
Let's see if passing the names as an argument helps.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector test_namesPassChar(int N, bool name,
                                       Rcpp::CharacterVector RNames) {

    Rcpp::RNGScope scope;
    Rcpp::NumericVector data = Rcpp::runif(N, 1, 100);

    if(name)data.attr("names")=RNames;

    return data;
}

microbenchmark(OP = test_names(10^5, T),
               passAndConvert = test_namesPassChar(10^5, T, 1:10^5),
               passAndConvert2 = test_namesPassChar(10^5, T, as.character(1:10^5)),
               unit = "relative")
               Unit: relative
           expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
             OP 0.9878606 1.0015865 0.9820272 1.000169 0.9471021 0.8645719   100
 passAndConvert 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.000000 1.0000000 1.0000000   100
passAndConvert2 1.0085636 0.9998202 1.0332923 1.000702 1.0517044 1.0507859   100
```

No luck here either.

It seems that if we really want to speed things up, we are going to have to define a vector of names upfront and subset that vector as needed.  For example, in your project if you know the maximum size of the named object you are wanting is `maxLength`, we can define `myNames <- as.character(1:maxLength)`.  Now in practice when we pass `N`, we also pass `myNames[1:N]`.

**Option pre-made names :**

```
maxLength <- 10^7
myNames <- as.character(1:maxLength) ## this steps takes a while, but you only do it once
microbenchmark(OP = test_names(10^5, T),
               passPreMade = test_namesPassChar(10^5, T, myNames[1:10^5]),
               unit = "relative")
               Unit: relative
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
         OP 8.149265 6.321411 6.617447 6.097933 6.042956 31.8545   100
passPreMade 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.0000   100
```

This is a nice improvement, but it still isn't that desirable because it isn't general.

Lastly, there is an option that I highly discourage, and I'm only mentioning it to show you why `Rcpp` is so nice.  We turn to `C` and we exploit the structure of incrementing integers to get our gains. `SET_STRING_ELT` expects an array of `chars` and normally, we would convert each integer *i* to a string via `temp = std::to_string(i)`, then convert `temp` to a char using the `.c_str()` function like so `myChar = temp.c_str()`.  This again, is just as slow as the first few methods because we are converting every integer from scratch to an array of `chars`. The good news in this scenario is that we don't need to this as we are simply naming our vector with the sequence `1:n`. So for 90% of our integers, only 1 digit is changing (i.e. the one's digit). Keeping this in mind, we can do something like this (N.B. this can definitely be improved as my C skills aren't strong):

**Option I don't recommend**

```
#include <R.h>
#include "Rinternals.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP test_namesSuperHard(int N, bool name) {
    Rcpp::RNGScope scope;
    Rcpp::NumericVector data = Rcpp::runif(N, 1, 100);

    if (name) {
        SEXP myNames = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(STRSXP, N));
        int base = (int) log10(N) + 1;
        char *myChar;
        myChar = (char *) malloc(base * sizeof(char));
        int count = 1, index = base - 1;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < base; i++)
            myChar[i] = '0';

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++, count++) {
            if ((count % 10) == 0) {
                while (myChar[index] == '9') {
                    myChar[index] = '0';
                    index--;
                }
                count = 0;
                myChar[index]++;
                index = base - 1;
            } else {
                myChar[index] = count + '0';
            }
            SET_STRING_ELT(myNames, i, Rf_mkChar(myChar));
        }
        Rf_setAttrib(data, R_NamesSymbol, myNames);
        UNPROTECT(1);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Test the output:

```
test_namesSuperHard(20, TRUE)
       01        02        03        04        05 
13.417850 29.633416 35.221770 17.377710 97.139458 
       06        07        08        09        10 
24.187230 60.962993 23.307580 61.151013 12.892655 
       11        12        13        14        15 
48.303439 28.875226 37.264403 78.196955 29.705689 
      16        17        18        19        20 
3.533349 86.505015 62.784809 95.785053 94.273097
```

And now we benchmark:

```
microbenchmark(OP = test_names(10^5, T),
               dontRecommend = test_namesSuperHard(10^5, T),
               unit = "relative")
               Unit: relative
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
           OP 3.753499 3.702676 3.885055 3.691977 3.504271 8.883482   100
dontRecommend 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```

And we see an improvement of almost `4x` as fast. Not bad. However, this is a lot of work for something that is, as I said in the opening, a convenience.  It also demonstrate the truly amazing work done by the `Rcpp` team (Dirk *et al.*) in making these *conveniences* effortless to implement.